# The description for the "unclear what you are asking" and "primarily opinion-based" close reasons need translation

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, international-sites, transifex

The descriptions for the *unclear what you are asking* and *primarily opinion-based* close reasons are not translated on any international site

SOes:

> [image: es.so close reasons]

SOpt:

> [image: pt.so close reasons]

SOja

> [image: ja.so close reasons]

SOru

> [image: ry.so close reasons]

I've searched on [traducir.win](https://traducir.win) and it looks like [there are several](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Many%20good) [translations for those strings](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Please%20clarify), so my guess is that those strings have to be added to transifex.

So, can you add them to transifex please?

Comment: Strings are on traducir. And already translated ;). There was a difference in the previous strings and the new one. A space was taken out.

Comment: @gbianchi so the translations will be there on the next build?

Comment: IDK (And I didn't look at them) if all of them are translated. There are more than only this one that you found... But some of them were already pushed.

Comment: I checked and they are there already, I need to work on my patience. Is strange though that for POB there are 3 equal strings for the description

Comment: They are not equal. The differs on spacing, tabs, and new lines ;)

Comment: So they are [_same same, but different, but still the same_](https://media.giphy.com/media/UI7EYk96rzq24/giphy.gif), noted, thanks man!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

sorry for this. We're doing a lot of refactoring in order to prep everything for the move to DotNet Core / AspNetCore. I've reverted the whitespace changes, the old strings will be used again as of build `2019.2.4.32802`.